# Assembler language basics parity flag

Tags: microcontroller, binary, assembler, parity, flag

I am a beginner in assembler language I was reading some stuff online(belongs to a university) and I saw that 
the P bit in psw after executing this instruction mov a,#03h  A=0000 0011B so P=0
first it was difficult to know what is p bit after some research I thought it is parity bit and then you have to count the number of one bits in the result so the number of 1 bit in the result is 2 so it is an even number so P must be equal to one so why is P equal to zero here ?

Comment: What microprocessor or microcontoller are you using?  Assembly language details like this may vary widely between different processor families.

Comment: it could be a Positive flag, the opposite of an N flag which is a negative bit/flag.  Without knowing what processor this is we cant really help...

Comment: @old_timer it is 8051

Comment: Wikipedia showed the answer: PSW.0: P Parity. Gives the parity (modulo-2 sum of the bits of) the accumulator, A.  Positive or negative parity is a simple test as Trevor shows in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably an even parity bit.

The count of all the bits that are ones **PLUS** the parity bit should be an even number.

Examples:

\$0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1\$ \$Parity = 0\$,  \$\Sigma= 2 + 0 = 2\$

\$0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1\$ \$Parity = 1\$,  \$\Sigma= 1 + 1 = 2\$

\$0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1\$ \$Parity = 0\$,  \$\Sigma= 4 + 0 = 4\$

\$0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1\$ \$Parity = 1\$, \$\Sigma= 5 + 1 = 6\$

Comment: How do you know if the parity is zero or one

Comment: @whyyoucare read the second line.